# Is it possible to utilize the `display:none` and `display:inline` to unhide nested hidden element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can inject CSS into the following code to affect the classes:

```
  <ul class="productText">
    <li>Thycotic Secret Server <span id="headerControl_VersionNumber" class="VersionNumber">8.8</span></li>
    <li class="EditionLabel"><span id="headerControl_EditionNameLabel" class="EditionName">Express Edition</span>  </li>
  </ul>
```

I'd like to utilize `:before` to replace the text `Thycotic Secret Server`, and I'd like to replace `Express Edition`.

Is it possible for me to use `display:none` against `.productText li{}` while maintaining visibility of either `.EditionLabel span{}` or `.EditionName :before`?

Such as:

```
  .productText:before {
      content:"to replace Thycotic Secret Server" !important;
  }

  .productText li{
      display:none !important;
  }

  .EditionName li{
      display:inline !important;
  }

  .EditionName:before {
      content:"to replace Express Edition" !important;
  }
```

...which clearly doesn't function since all sub-elements of `.productText` of type `li` are hidden.

Is what I'm trying to do possible given the code to be modified?

**[solution]**

Since all text "within" all `li` elements has it's `font-size` set to 0, I used more specific elements to control properties.

```
  .productText li{
    font-size: 0;
  }

  .productText:before {
    font-size: 1rem;
    content:"replaced larger text"
    font-variant:small-caps;
  }

  .EditionName:after {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    content:"replaced smaller text"
  }
```

In this specific example, I located the `font-size` for EditionName in the original CSS and transferred it into this set to maintain the same look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with the `font-size`, e.g.

```
li { font-size: 0; }
li span { font-size: 1rem; }
li span:before { content:"to replace Thycotic Secret Server "; }
```

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxarjd

Comment: Thank you!  Your response lead me to my answer as appended above.